# AppleScript - Extract Text from website after certain label id

Tags: applescript

I need to extract text from website using applescript and Safari.

The text string I need to extract is always located here:

```
<label id="DIL" style="display: inline;">THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT</label>
```

I've tried using the following code:

```
 to getInputById(theId)

    tell application "Safari"

        set input to do JavaScript "

document.getElementById('" & theId & "').innerHTML;" in document 1

    end tell

    return input

end getInputById

getInputById("DIL")
```

But the Extracted text string is always empty ""

Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Both your AppleScript and JavaScript are fine, so there's something else going on which is stopping your script from working.  Can you provide a link to the webpage from which you wish to extract the content ?

Comment: this code works fine when I try to extract text from form inputs. The label with ID is a javascript text, so I need an applescript code to extract the text inside of this tags from the source code.